# Como trabajar con un form dividido en varios divs

Tags: html

Desde que uso HTML no he seguido ningún 'manual' para saber si lo que funciona realmente esta hecho de la mejor forma, una vez tuve un conflicto con un form y lo solucione pero hoy quiero confirmar si esta bien.

Primera alternativa:

```
<div class='card'>
   <div class='card-header'>Registrar</div>
   <div class='card-body'>
      <form>
         <div>
            <label>Ejemplo1</label>
            <input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label>Ejemplo2</label>
            <input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label>Ejemplo3</label>
            <input>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class='card-footer'>
       <button value='Enviar'></button>
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Primera alternativa]

Segundo alternativa

```
<div class='card'>
   <div class='card-header'>Registrar</div>
   <form>
      <div class='card-body'>
         <div>
            <label>Ejemplo1</label>
            <input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label>Ejemplo2</label>
            <input>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label>Ejemplo3</label>
            <input>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class='card-footer'>
         <button value='Enviar'></button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

[image: Segunda alternativa]

Como podemos ver podría realizar el mismo diseño con cualquiera de esas dos formas, pero quiero saber cual es la mejor y por qué? Supongo que la segunda, se ve mas limpio y ordenado aunque ambas funcionan.

El problema que veo en la segunda alternativa es que los elementos del footer pierden el diseño de esa clase.

En resumen: Esta mal abrir un form en un div y cerrarlo en otro diferente?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, el lenguaje de etiquetas funciona como contenedores, donde cada etiqueta debe abrir y cerrar, y dentro puedes meter mas y mas contenedores. Cruzar contenedores no deberia de ser correcto, porque deforma la estructura, Eso lleva despues a problemas de dise;o dentro del mismo html.

En tu primer ejemplo, estas cruzando un  con una  a la mitad. lo cual es incorrecto.

La segunda opcion esta correcta, porque abres el contenedor del  y dentro acomodas los demas  y ya despues cierras ese contenedor.

Solo velo de esa manera, contenedores.

Comment: Queda claro, pero una duda no se porque con boostrap al aplicar la segunda alternativa parece que pierde el diseño de las clases, por ejemplo en card-footer ya todo me queda sin bordes.

Comment: Porfa, puedes revisar las imagenes

Comment: en bootstrap la idea del card es poner todo dentro de un card-body , card-footer, o card-header es como esta dise;ado su css. eso significa o que tienes que pasar el form dentro del card-body

Comment: O tambien puedes mover los tags del form para contener dentro del el el card

Comment: Perfecto, puse que el form contenga al .card. Es la mejor solución?

Comment: No, la mejor solución es que el `form` quede contenido dentro del `.card-body`, tanto su inicio como su cierre

Comment: Exactamente, la mejor seria que el contenido quedase dentro del card-body. pero html es muy versatil.